# Pass Func into List.Find

Tags: c#, func

I have the following code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void A_Player_Can_Be_Deleted_From_The_List()
    {                     
        Player player = playerList.Find(ByName("Davy",whatGoesHere?);
        playerList.Remove(player);

        playerList.Count.Should().Be(2);
    }
```

The Func 'ByName' is defined as:

```
Func<string, Player, bool> ByName = (name, player) => player.Name == name;
```

I don't know how to pass the second (player) parameter.  Is it possible?

Comment: The `Player` is provided by `List.Find` - it looks like you want `ByName(string name) { return p => p.Name == name; }`. Your example won't compile since there's no overload of `List<T>.Find` which takes a `Func<string, T, bool>`.

Comment: This will also work `playerList.Find(p => ByName("Davy", p));`

Comment: @nemesv You should add that as the answer, I think. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `player` is provided to a predicate you pass to `List.Find<T>`, so you can just pass that to `ByName`:

```
Player player = playerList.Find(p => ByName("Davy", p));
playerList.Remove(player);
```

Instead of using `Find` and `Remove` you can use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) i.e.

```
playerList.RemoveAll(p => ByName("Davy", p));
```

Comment: If he didn't want to use a delegate but wanted to use a method, I would have though he wouldn't detail the delegate...  Seems like it misses the point of the question.

Comment: @davy - What doesn't compile?

Comment: @Lee - sorry, removed the comment and accepted answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `ByName` delegate in the `Find` Method you have to execute it for each element in the list.  For example:

```
string player = playerList.Find((playerElement) => ByName("Davy", playerElement));
```

Comment: The parentheses around `playerElement` are not necessary.

Comment: @svick.  Yes, they're not necessary.